# Android moving buttons and background in runtime

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I'm trying to make a tab look-A-like buttons row with a background that is an ImageView.

Here is the ImageView:

[image]

now on this image there are three buttons when the fragment loads.

[image]

when i click button one:
there are two situations:
1) when screen looks like the image above, then i want to move the buttons to the right so the screen looks like this:

[image]

and when it looks like the image above, i want it to return to the first image state.

the last case is when a user press's B3 i want it to react the same as B1 but to the other side, like this:

[image]

I tried so far lots of methods to try this, all have not worked, it seems that when i animate the movement the buttons stay in the same place:

here is my code so far:

```
btn_spa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                isMapPressed=false;
                isInfoPressed=false;
                int toMoveNow=0;
                if(!isSpaPressed)
                {

                    if(isMapPressed)
                        toMoveNow=(toMove/2)+40;
                    else
                        toMoveNow=-(toMove/2+40);
                    int[] arr = new int[]{0,0};

                    btn_spa.getLocationOnScreen(arr);

                    Animation animation  = new TranslateAnimation(arr[0], toMoveNow, 0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    //rel_buttons_wrapper.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_info.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_map.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_spa.startAnimation(animation);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button spa clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                isSpaPressed=false;
                isInfoPressed=false;
                int toMoveNow=0;
                if(!isMapPressed && isSpaPressed)
                {
                    toMoveNow=-(toMove/2+40);
                    int[] arr = new int[]{0,0};
                    btn_map.getLocationOnScreen(arr);
                    Animation animation  = new TranslateAnimation(arr[0], toMoveNow, 0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                //  rel_buttons_wrapper.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_info.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_map.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_spa.startAnimation(animation);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button map clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    toMoveNow=(toMove/2+40);
                    int[] arr = new int[]{0,0};
                    btn_map.getLocationOnScreen(arr);
                    Animation animation  = new TranslateAnimation(arr[0], toMoveNow, 0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                //  rel_buttons_wrapper.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_info.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_map.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_spa.startAnimation(animation);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button map clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                int toMoveNow=0;
                if(!isInfoPressed && isSpaPressed)
                {
                    toMoveNow=(toMove/2)+40;
                    int[] arr = new int[]{0,0};
                    btn_info.getLocationOnScreen(arr);
                    Animation animation  = new TranslateAnimation(arr[0], toMoveNow, 0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    rel_buttons_wrapper.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_info.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_map.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_spa.startAnimation(animation);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button info clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    toMoveNow=-(toMove/2);
                    int[] arr = new int[]{0,0};
                    btn_info.getLocationOnScreen(arr);
                    Animation animation  = new TranslateAnimation(arr[0], toMoveNow, 0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    rel_buttons_wrapper.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_info.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_map.startAnimation(animation);
                    btn_spa.startAnimation(animation);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button info clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                isSpaPressed=false;
                isMapPressed=false;

            }
        });
```

Sorry for the long question, I wanted to be as informative as possible.

any help would be good guys,

Kind Regards.

Comment: So if I am correct you want the bottom to be a sliding compass-like motion that points to indicate the currently chosen fragment?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ObjectAnimator class, it moves views and their bounds so they actually move when you move them, here is a tutorial :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator